# Include Wordpress Login Form into a Page to protect it

Tags: php, wordpress

hope you can help me and I hope I write it correct:

I've a WP Page with content. If a user isn't logged in, a login form with the possibility to register should be shown. after login, the content of the page should be shown, The rest of my WP Pages doesn't need this.

I've tried this:

```
   <form style="text-align: left;" action="http://fragandy.com/mein-konto/" method="GET">
        ' . $errors . '
            <p>
                <label for="log"><input id="user_login" name="log" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Type Username or Email" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 45px;"> '
                . apply_filters( 'pr_username_label', 'Username' ) . '</label><br />
                <label for="pwd"><input id="user_pass" name="pwd" class="input" type="password" placeholder="Type Password" style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 45px;"> ' 
                . apply_filters( 'pr_password_label' , 'Password' ) . '</label><br />
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" class="button" />
                <label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> Remember me</label><br />
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" />
        </form>
```

Any ideas ??

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the native [**Password Protection**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection) won't suit your needs, you have a few options, despite the fact there are definitely some plugins that do this, but I can't recommend any of them specifically.

---

## Option 1: Filter `the_content` based on the post_id or slug.

Basically, you can use the [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter and conditionally filter out the content and replace it with a login form and/or login/register links. Here's a snippet that will activate on post id `123` (replace that with the ID of your actual page). If you need a one-and-done solution, I'd probably go this route:

```
function require_login_for_content( $content ){
    global $post;
    
    if( $post->ID == 123 ){
        if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){
            $redirect = get_permalink();

            $content  = sprintf('<h4>Please <a href="%s">Log In</a> or <a href="%s">Register</a> to view this content.</h4>', wp_login_url( $redirect ), wp_registration_url() );
            $content .= wp_login_form( array( 'redirect' => get_permalink(), 'echo' => false ) );
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'require_login_for_content' );
```

---

## Option 2: Create a [**Page Template**](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

This may make more sense if you need to have this available on more than one page without editing code or managing an array of post ids. Go in to your theme and copy your `page.php` or equivalent file, and name it something like `page-login-required.php`. Now, depending on your theme, the *exact* methodolgy will be different. I'll use the TwentySeventeen theme as an example.

Add the following line to the comment section at the top: `Template Name: Login Required` so it looks something like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Login Required
 *
 * The template for displaying all pages
 …
```

This will allow you to select it as a Page Template named "Login Required" in the page editor on the right hand side of the page. Now, where the page pulls in the content ( again, this will be different for every theme ), in this case on what's now line 30, `get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'page' );`.

You can wrap that with the [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) function and make use of the [`wp_login_form()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form):

```
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();

    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'page' );

        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;
    } else {
        printf('<h4>Please <a href="%s">Log In</a> or <a href="%s">Register</a> to view this content.</h4>', wp_login_url( $redirect ), wp_registration_url() );
        wp_login_form( array( 'redirect' => get_permalink() ) );
    }

endwhile; // End of the loop.
```

Now save that and select it as the page template, and you should be good to go.

You can also do something similar using [**Shortcodes**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), but I think it makes more sense to keep the content blocking done in the template.

---

There's a few other things you could do, but I'd evaluate the above options before weighing in any other ones.